# primeng fileUpload to send form data and passing file array to the service layer

Tags: java, angular, rest, primeng

I am using p-fileUpload primeng component. I have a requirement where in addition to the files selected another p-multiselect in the form has to be submitted along. Below is the working code for fileupload.

When I choose and click upload it uploads the file. I want to change `uploadFileCtr($event)` to `uploadFileCtr($event,faqForm.value )` and pass the commented code in `uploadFileCtr()` method in the ts file. I tried and added this line to the service.ts formdata:

```
formData.append("faqObj", faqObj);
```

However, I couldn't get the object in my rest service. I tried to include another param in my POST method: `@FormDataParam("faqObj") Faq`. This gives me error.

My component.html look like this

```
<form [formGroup]="faqForm" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" multiple="multiple" accept=".xlsx" customUpload="true"
                    (uploadHandler)="uploadFileCtr($event)">
            </p-fileUpload>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label >Board ID(s) *:</label>
            <p-multiSelect [options]="boards" formControlName="board" [defaultLabel]="'All Active Boards'" (onChange)="displayBoard($event)"></p-multiSelect> 
        </div> 
        <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf = "show">
            <label >Board Title:</label>
            <input class="pInputFilter pInputTxt" type="text" readonly id="boardname" value={{this.userSelectedBoard}}>  
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

component.cs for uploadFileCtr is as below

```
uploadFileCtr(event) { 
      // faqObj.faqBoards =  faqObj.board.map(boardId=>{
      //   let boardObj:Board = new Board();
      //   boardObj.id = boardId; 
      //   return boardObj;
      // });
        for (let file of event.files) {
          this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
        }
        this.faqService.uploadFile(this.uploadedFiles).subscribe( posts =>{
            this.data = posts;
        },
        error => console.log("Error: ", error),
        () => {
            this.errMsg = this.data.error; 
            // this.succMsg = this.data.success;  
            if (this.errMsg) {
                console.log("errMsg: ", this.errMsg);
                this.msgs = [];
                this.msgs.push({severity:'error', summary:'Error Message', detail:this.data.error});                
                this.status = "error";
            } else {
                // this.getCaseDocuments();
                this.msgs = [];
                this.msgs.push({severity:'success', summary:'Success Message', detail:this.data.success});                             
            }
        
        });
        this.faqForm.reset();
    }
```

Service.ts for the upload REST service is

```
uploadFile( uploadedFiles: any[]){
    let file: File = null;
    let formData:FormData = new FormData(); 
    if (uploadedFiles != null && uploadedFiles.length > 0) {
        file = uploadedFiles[0];
    }      
    if (file != null) {
        formData.append("file", file);
        formData.append("fileName", file.name);
    } else {
        formData.append("file", null);            
        formData.append("fileName", "");
    }
    return this.http.post(this.faqServiceURL +"/upload", formData, { 'headers': this.headers });
}
```

}

```
@POST
@Path("upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("application/json")
public Response upload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream is,
                           @FormDataParam("fileName") String fileName){
    logger.info("FaqService - upload");
    System.out.println("upload : "+fileName+"  faqObj : "); 
    ObjectMapper mapper = utilityObj.getMapperObj();
    String jsonInString = "";  ..//////
    
    }
```

1. Can I add formobj along with the upload - if so, how?
2. How can I send multiple files? formData.append("file", file); - this doesn't accept an array

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**- Can I add formObj along with the upload - if so, how?

If you have to send the whole object in the formData there are 2 ways,

1. Stringify the object like- `formData.append("faqObj", JSON.stringify(faqObj));`
   In this case, the server will have to parse the stringified object.
2. Another way to do it is to append the keys of the object looping through the object like **Object.keys(faqObj).forEach(ele => formData.append(`faqObj[${ele}]`), faqObj[ele])**
   In this case, the server does not have to parse the object.

**Question 2-** How can I send multiple files? formData.append("file", file); - this doesnt accept an array

For this, you have to loop through the files array as follows

```
uploadedFiles.forEach(file => formData.append('file[]', file))
```

Comment: answer to 1 worked using stringfy. thank you. For 2: i can send fileArray. I have another question . How can i loop through the array get the file and convert them to byte stream and fileName too for each file. Is there any working example? I tried different ways but couldnt find a solution for multiple file upload so far.

Comment: I am using REST service to get the file and save to DB. Using multi form data and @FormDataParam but not able to get the data and iterate

Comment: I am not clear on what you mean. You can check the primeng documentation for knowing how to read the file.